# complex sorting PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

ok here is what i want to do :

> **I dont want to perform the sorting in my sql query**

My database schema for students address is shared below:

CITY   (mandatory)     | AREA   (mandatory)    | ROAD  (optional)  | BUILDING_NAME (optional)

i want to sort (group) the students

> 1. CITY , then within the city sort(group) student by
> 2. AREA , withing area sort (group) students by
> 3. ROAD , note 2 cities have a possibility of having the same road name , soo..

this is what i have done till now :

i have managed to sort(group) the student by CITY ,(which is a object $student that has all the information not just address but all related information to the student, and is not sorted by CITY name), now within the city i want to group the student that belong to same area and same road within a city.How i can i achieve this

I hope i have explained it clearly

Example :

> ```
> NAME           CITY         AREA       ROAD      BUILDING NAME
> ```

1. > 1. demo_student    new york  four square   downtown  sea mist

> 1. sample          new york  zzpq          zzar      deni
> 2. check           mumbai    thane         mg road    abc
> 3. hello           mumbai    andheri       some      demo
> 4. sammy           mumbai    bandra        abc        ll
>
> OUTPUT

```
NAME           CITY         AREA       ROAD      BUILDING NAME
```

1. > 1. demo_student    new york  four square   downtown  sea mist

> 1. sample          new york  zzpq          zzar      deni
> 2. hello           mumbai    andheri       some      demo
> 3. sammy           mumbai    bandra        abc        ll
> 4. check           mumbai    thane         mg road    abc

Comment: you should really reconsider sorting in SQL.

Comment: You should user sql: order by. This does exactly what you want much faster than you could do it in php

Comment: some examples about the excpected results will be helpful

Comment: Could you please explain why don't you want to sort using SQL?

Comment: If you don't want to sort using SQL, then don't show your schema and instead show the PHP code

Comment: @Jack the schema was just to explain the hierarchy of address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and a custom function to compare two rows and work out which one goes first. You can write it to be as complex as you like.

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>

The above example will output:

0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 5
4: 6
```

Now, with that out of the way, for goodness sake, ignore this answer and do it in the SQL query. It will be quicker than PHP will ever be able to do it, consume less resources and be *much* easier to update should you want to change something in the order.

Comment: point taken , did realise it would be more efficient to do it on mysql , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is done using a map of  list>

The implementation will probably loop on the potential members (the students) and dispatch them to the adequate list. The map can be populated with groups on the fly, or pre-populated if you know all of the groups.

The idea is not to identify that 2 students belong to the same group, but rather to identify the group in which each student belongs.

also, please don't say sort when you mean group.